# Atmel ASF on SAM - pio_configure_pin wrong described?

Tags: arm, atmel

I am biting my lips off from trying my first steps with the ASF provided by Atmel.

It seems like the ASF is written inefficient in many places and on top the documentation seems to be inaccurate or I am already too burned out to think straight.

The most current problem that costed me many hours:

```
pio_configure_pin() versus pio_configure_pin_group()
```

Described here: http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/sam3u/html/group__sam__drivers__pio__group.html#ga66c09a2f5c8d11223eb107cf8fbfddb2

**Based on the documentation:**
The first parameter of configure_pin : ul_pin   Bitmask of one or more pin(s) to configure
The second parameter of configure_pin_group: ul_mask    Bitmask of one or more pin(s) to configure

**In reality :**
first parameter of configure_pin is NOT a bitmask.
If I want to configure Pin PB 28 I have to use the value 60 !

```
#define PIO_PB28_IDX 60
```

If I want to configure the same Pin using the group function I have to use the value 2415919104

```
#define PIO_PB28 (1u << 28)
```

The wrong documentation, lack of examples and forum entries with wrong examples led me to a loss of many hours.
If I am wrong here please let me know, maybe I missed something from the documentation.
After all the PIO driver is most likely one of the most important ones, it is required for almost any usage of the chip.. And these two functions are really important ones.

Maybe an expert with Atmel SAM could help me decide if it is worth at all to continue using the ASF ?
Do experts use it for their development or is it better to write everything from scratch.

For me it seemed that when coming from AVR development suddenly all the easyness is gone and ASF was Atmels way to make it easier again, however if it is buggy and not in a proper release state it might be useless.

Answer (score 0):

It is alright. Errors are often happen to documentation. Be positive. You discovered it now you are master. Seriously, it is not a big deal. Once you found it put in a macro or use your own functions for such PIO access. I would always prefer to open a header and see how does one macro or function access required bit fields. It is a bit wise magic in there. It often goes close to deep and low level understanding of a particular architecture, which is fine for developer. It is worth spending hours in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this function.
Parameter **ul_pin** is actually a sequential number of a pin. As seen in the function, it is used firstly to point ***Pio*** pointer to correct ***PIO*** controller by finding out how many 32-based blocks in that sequential number.

So you are right, that is an error in documentation.